# iOS NSMutableString returns weird character

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, nsarray, nsmutablestring

I make an array of several words, then I put all words into a mutable string, and then a mutable array of every character of this string. However, "wordSplitted" that is a mutable array of the characters give random scrambled characters at each startup of app in Simulator, showing in the log:

```
2012-07-22 09:12:01.108 xxx[4484:b603] wordSplitted contains: (
    "",
    "",
    "\U221e",
    "-",
    G,
    N,
    P,
    "",
    ""
)
```

It should be b, i, l, h, u, k, s, k, j.

```
   NSArray *threeWords = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"bil", @"huk", @"skje", nil];


    NSMutableString *allTogether = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];

    /*
    for (NSString *s in threeWords)
    {
        [allTogether appendString:s];
    }
     */

    for (int b = 0; b < [threeWords count]; b++)
    {
        [allTogether appendString:[threeWords objectAtIndex:b]];
    }
    NSLog (@"allTogether contains %@", allTogether);

    //[threeWords release];
    [allTogether release];

    NSMutableArray *wordSplitted = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

//this function gives me headache
        for (int a = 0; a < 9; a ++)
        {
            //gives also scrambled characters

        //[wordSplitted addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C",[allTogether characterAtIndex:a]]];

        NSRange range = {a,1};

        [wordSplitted addObject:[allTogether substringWithRange:range]];

    }

    NSLog (@"wordSplitted contains: %@", wordSplitted);
```

How can I display normal characters like alphabets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You call `[allTogether release]` but then reference it later on. Normally this would cause your program to crash, but something about the `CFMutableArray` backing makes this not always happen.

Basically, don't release the array until you're sure you're done using it.

Answer (score 1):

about string splitting

http://www.idev101.com/code/Objective-C/Strings/split.html